# Obtaining month and year from date on large vector

Tags: r, date

I have a vector with n elements.

Obtaining year and month from a vector with one object is easy

```
a <- as.Date("01.01.2001", "%d.%m.%Y")
b <- format(a, "%Y%m")
```

But, how to do that if I would have 1k different dates in a vector?

When I replace my vector with one element with my vector with n elements I get

> Error in format.default(structure(as.character(x), names = names(x), dim = dim(x),  : 
>     invalid 'trim' argument

dput of my vector I try to convert

```
"02.01.2011 00:00", "02.04.2000 00:00",...
```

Comment: Just do the same and replace `"01.01.2001"` by the name of your vector

Comment: Please `dput` (a part of) your vector

Comment: Works for me. there must be a part of your vector with a different format

Comment: @etienne its all converted to date format with `as.Date()`. Did not throw back any error.

Comment: Could you `sort` your vector (before or after `as.Date`) and return the `head` and the `tail` of it ?

Comment: @etienne I ceated my vector from a dataframe. the format in the column changed somehow back to factor after converting it to date. on factor the function did not work...

Comment: Did you try to launch the 2 functions in one call, ie `format(as.Date(x,'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'),'%Y%m')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
your.character.vector <- c("02.01.2011 00:00", "02.04.2000 00:00")

a <- as.POSIXct(your.character.vector, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
# or, if time is not always 00:00
a <- as.POSIXct(your.character.vector, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")

c <- as.POSIXlt(a)$mday
d <- as.POSIXlt(a)$mon + 1  # + 1 because mon = 0-11
b <- paste0(c,d)

> b
[1] "21" "24"

# or to add leading zeros where they are missing
b <- paste0(sprintf("%02d",c), sprintf("%02d",d))

> b
[1] "0201" "0204"
```